# Array of structs returns errors

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I have the following code:

```
static int gridX = 40;
static int gridY = 40;

public struct CubeStruct
{
    public Transform cube;
    public bool alive;
    public Color color;
}

public CubeStruct cubeArray[,] = new CubeStruct[gridX, gridY];
```

This returns the following errors:

> error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `,' in class, struct, or interface
>   member declaration
>
> error CS0178: Invalid rank specifier: expected `,' or`]'
>
> error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `;' in class, struct, or interface
>   member declaration

It's probably something obvious, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, the `[,]` go before the name of the variable (i.e. it is not like in C/C++).

```
public CubeStruct[,] cubeArray = new CubeStruct[gridX, gridY];
```

Comment: I'm quite ashamed that I missed it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
public CubeStruct cubeArray[,] = new CubeStruct[gridX, gridY];
```

should be:

```
public CubeStruct[,] cubeArray = new CubeStruct[gridX, gridY];
```

Answer (score 3):

<del>In C#, nothing can float around outside of a Type. So you need to do this:</del>
Also note that the [,] comes after the *type*, not after the *identifier*.

```
public class GridMain
{
    static int gridX = 40;
    static int gridY = 40;
    public CubeStruct[,] cubeArray = new CubeStruct[gridX, gridY];

}

public struct CubeStruct
{
    public Transform cube;
    public bool alive;
    public Color color;
}
```

Comment: Of course, my code is IN a class. I just copy/pasted the relevant bit.

Comment: sure, that wasn't clear from your question. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
public CubeStruct cubeArray[,] = new CubeStruct[gridX, gridY];
```

to:

```
public CubeStruct[,] cubeArray = new CubeStruct[gridX, gridY];
```